# Opening a file after writing to it

Tags: c#, winforms, file, epplus

I have a small app that writes to an excel file.

I would like for the program to immediately open the file after it has finished saving it.

How to go about doing just that?

Using Epplus to handle the excel.

Comment: Please don't stack your title with tags, it isn't necessary.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if u just want to open file in C# u can just import

```
using System.Diagnostics;
```

then u can run process for "xlsx" file with `Process.Start(string path);`

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Process.Start(@"C:\your.xlsx");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Process process = new Process();

 process.StartInfo.FileName = "excel.exe";
 process.StartInfo.Arguments = "myfyle.xls";
 process.Start();
```